# Having trouble with adding one property to an object inside a list after assigning the rest of them

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been having trouble (again) with some object-oriented code.

Currently I have a piece of code that populates a list with objects and its properties that goes like this:

```
foreach (var folder in pathList)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        fileinfoList.Add(new FileInfo()
            {
                partNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Convert.ToString(file)),
                fileType = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(file)),
                lastDate = file.LastWriteTime,
                released = 1,
                checkedBy = null,
                fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Convert.ToString(folder)),
            });
    }
}
```

What I need is to add the `baseID` property to each of the objects. This is what I have currently:

```
foreach (var item in fileNameList)
{
    if (fileinfoList.Select(m => m.partNumber == dummyString.ToString()) != null)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"data source = MYPC\SQLEXPRESS; database = MYDB; integrated security = TRUE";
        string query = $@"SELECT id FROM MYTABLE WHERE fullpath= '{pathsToFilesNotOnDbList[y]}' ";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            iD = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["id"]);
            fileinfoList.Select (f => f.baseID = iD) ;
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            y++;
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I want this loop to take the value of `iD` and assign it to the `baseID` property.

I can get the `iD`'s just fine, however I'm aware that the lambda expression `fileinfoList.Select (f => f.baseID = iD)` does nothing currently.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: To which element of `fileinfoList` you want to assign the `iD` value? All of them?

Comment: Yes, i want to assign an `iD` value to each of the `baseID` properties of all the object in the list

Comment: Besides, GetFileNameWithoutExtension and GetExtension and GetFullPath return string type and you don't need to convert to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `baseId = iD` to all the elements of the list `fileinfoList`, just use:

```
fileinfoList.ForEach(i => i.baseID = iD);
```

**UPDATE**: set different `id` to each element:

```
var index = 0;
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    iD = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["id"]);
    fileinfoList[index].baseID = id;
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    y++;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but every object of the `fileInfoList` has a different value for `baseID`

Comment: It retrieves 12 values

Comment: Compare fileinfoList list with dataReader by (fullPath + partNumber + fileType) because It's unique then set the Id.

Comment: @Fernando Araujo, and fileInfoList has the same number of elements retrieved by the query?

Comment: Yep, the `fileInfoList` list has 12 objects inside, and i need to assign the value of `iD` to each of it's `baseID` properties

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you need to know which object in `fileinfoList` you want to update with each `id` value.

Assuming `fullpath` field is unique across the dataset and an identifier for the object in `fileinfoList` as well as `MYTABLE` you can make the following updates and it should work for you:

**Update Query to include `fullpath` field in returned data:**

`string query = $@"SELECT id, fullpath FROM MYTABLE WHERE fullpath= '{pathsToFilesNotOnDbList[y]}' ";`

**Update assignment statement to filter `fileinfoList` by `fullpath` before attempting to assign the value from the db:**

`fileinfoList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.fullpath == dataReader["fullPath"]).baseID = iD;`

**Full code:**

```
foreach (var item in fileNameList)
{
    if (fileinfoList.Select(m => m.partNumber == dummyString.ToString()) != null)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"data source = MYPC\SQLEXPRESS; database = MYDB; integrated security = TRUE";
        string query = $@"SELECT id, fullpath FROM MYTABLE WHERE fullpath= '{pathsToFilesNotOnDbList[y]}' ";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            iD = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["id"]);
            fileinfoList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.fullpath == dataReader["fullPath"]).baseID = iD;
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            y++;
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked after converting the right hand side to string like so : `fileinfoList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.fullPath == dataReader["fullPath"].ToString()).baseID = iD;` , Thanks!